# Magento :Password reset link is not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

i am trying to reset my test customer account password for my store, when i click on forgot password link it is asking me for a email address when i enter a valid email address it says the password reset link is sent to your mail & it is forwarding me a link in email when i click on the link it is displaying an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function setCustomerId() on a non-object in /var/www/websites/jivity/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php on line 587`  , How can i fix this error?? & Thanx in advance.

Comment: What method is that in? My line 587 in a 1.5.1.0 distro doesn't call setCustomerId()

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?

Comment: I'm using a latest version of magento i,e. magento-1.6

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just fixed the same problem on an upgraded 1.6.1.0 site - You are using an out of date customers.xml, diff your copy and `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml` to find the changes that need doing

Comment: Used the same fix on a 1.7.0.2 site. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

If anyone is wondering, in the new version (1.6++) of the customer.xml file the following bit has been added:

```
<customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_resetpassword>
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem for me on Magento 1.6.2

Comment: Fixed mine on Mangento 1.9.1 (from 1.5)

Answer (score 3):

If you are in **Magento 1.9.1** Here is a solution which worked for me.

If your theme doesn’t include any specific custom config or layout settings you can safely **delete** your customer.xml (or just rename to customer1.xml) file located at `/app/design/frontend/default/<your_theme_package>/<your_theme_name>/layout/customer.xml`

> If you delete this file magento will load the default config options
>   (with the updates) from the factory default magento theme. 
>   /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml

*Remember to flush / refresh your magento config via administration area, this will force the customer.xml file to be reloaded.*

Comment: The same is valid for Magento 1.7 after a critic patch update (6788) started giving this problem in certain installations.

Answer (score 1):

please add below code in your costomer.xml[app/design/frontend///layout/customer.xml] file.

```
<customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
        <label>Reset a Password</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
                <title>Reset a Password</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
                <title>Reset a Password</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_resetpassword>
```

It's Working

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above, but didn't work. From another tip I saw, I added the same code above to the 'mageb2bextensionscustomer.xml' in the same layout folder, cleared all the cache and it works now. :-)

Comment: It is because your extension is overriding the default customer xml.

Answer (score 0):

**Always back up your files!**

I found a fast way to solve the issue: I replaced the custom `customer.xml` used by my theme in `app/design/frontend/your_theme_package/your_theme_name/layout/` with the file in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml`.

Now it works just fine.